# Добавить цвет фона в нумерованный список

Tags: html, css, list

У меня есть нумерованный список с номерами 1,2,3 и т.д. Как добавить цвет фона к номерам 1,2,3, а также удалить точку после каждого из этих номеров?

```
<ol>
    <li>Prep ingredients and Sauté if required.</li>
    <li>Add ingredients to inner pot.</li>
    <li>Close the lid. Set release to 0.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54152724/7394871

Answer (score 3):

### 1#

Вот более динамичный способ с использованием CSS-переменных:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: count;
}

ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ol li:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content: counter(count)" ";
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 5px;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#fff;
  background:var(--c,red);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li >Red here</li>
  <li style="--c:yellow">Yellow here</li>
  <li style="--c:blue">Blue here</li>
  <li style="--c:orange">Orange here</li>
  <li style="--c:green">Green here</li>
</ol>
```

### 2#

```css
.bg-yellow:before {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    .bg-red:before {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .bg-green:before {
      background-color: green;
    }
    .bg-orange:before {
      background-color: orange;
    }
    .bg-aqua:before {
      background-color: aqua;
    }
    ol {
      counter-reset: myOrderedListItemsCounter;
    }
    ol li {
      list-style-type: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    ol li:before {
      counter-increment: myOrderedListItemsCounter;
      content: counter(myOrderedListItemsCounter)" ";
      margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
<ol>
      <li class="bg-yellow">Yellow here</li>
      <li class="bg-red">Red here</li>
      <li class="bg-orange">Orange here</li>
      <li class="bg-green">Green here</li>
      <li class="bg-aqua">Aqua here</li>
    </ol>
```